# Transitions between states in a simple Java game

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a simple slide-scrolling game which should have a user menu with two buttons (both are custom-made images) on launch - Play and Exit. The problem is that I don't how to link the first (Play) option to the frame containing the actual program (see code below) - i.e. when pressed, the game itself begins. I have the same issue with the Exit possibility.

Looking forward to any suggestions concerning the implementation of active buttons and smooth transitions.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame {

    public Frame(){

       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       frame.add(new Board());
       frame.setTitle("2-D Test Game");
       Image im = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("img.png");
       frame.setIconImage (im);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.setSize(800,500);
       frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
       new Frame();
    }
}
```

Comment: @sstan I know, but Kara resurrected it with a minor edit... I just had it edited again, see edit history; alright see the meta [burninate-request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333913/moving-out-transition?cb=1) for the `transition` tag.